# VLC source code - setup/installer

Tags: windows, installation, vlc

I downloaded the source code of VLC but there is no setup source file. Can I find it somewhere and what setup compiler it is using? I need it to see what operations are made while installing.

Comment: What are ‘setup source file’ and ‘setup compiler’?!

Comment: Something like Inno Setup and .iss (project) files.

Comment: It took me a whole two minutes to find this: https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/

Comment: Compile what? You cannot understand what is Application and what is Application Setup (installator). I need to compile VLC _Setup_ and not the VLC itself!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what ‘VLC Setup’ is.

Comment: VLC Setup (installer) is the EXE program which you download from videolan.org. When you run it, you have installed VLC.exe in Program Files. Setup/Installer can be EXE or MSI file (MSI is Microsoft Installer). To produce it you need setup compiler like Inno Setup and the corresponding "project" file.

Comment: [The last section of that page](https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/#Packaging_VLC) describes how to build the installer, also known as a package and, apparently, ‘setup’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it. It is in "vlc_x_x_x\extras\package\win32". The installer is NSIS.